# Swift: Convert string to hex color code

Tags: swift

I have generated user Ids (with a format like ""XzSYoKJaqKYREkdB2dgwt0fLOPP2"") from a database that I would like to use to create an UIColor.

I found several [solutions](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift) on how to crate an UIColor with a color hex code, but I don't quite know how I would generate a color hex code (#ffffff) from a string like the one above. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are all user IDs very different from each other?

Comment: You want a random color for each generated user Ids string ?

Comment: All the IDs have the format like the one above (firebase user.uid). I would like to create an unique color (if possible) from these strings.

Comment: There are more possible unique user ids in that format than possible color combinations. A 28 character user id where each characters can be one of 42 (at least characters) means there are 42^28 (roughly 2.8E45) user ids. But a color is RGB where each has 256 values for a total of 256^3 (roughly 1.6E7).

Comment: @maddy, I think the main problem is not uniqueness here. OP just wants to create a constant color for each user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are far too many user ids to get a unique color for every possible user id. Your best option would be to find a way to narrow down each user id to one of the possible available colors and accept the fact that two users may have the same color.

One possible solution is would be to get the `hashValue` of the user id string and then reduce that `Int` down to one of the possible 16,777,216 colors.

```
let userId = "XzSYoKJaqKYREkdB2dgwt0fLOPP2" // or whatever the id is
let hash = abs(userId.hashValue)
let colorNum = hash % (256*256*256)
```

At this point `colorNum` is the range `0` - `0xFFFFFF`

You can now create a color from `colorNum`.

```
let red = colorNum >> 16
let green = (colorNum & 0x00FF00) >> 8
let blue = (colorNum & 0x0000FF)
let userColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red)/255.0, green: CGFloat(green)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

You will want to store this color in the user's profile since the `hashValue` isn't guaranteed to be the same each time your app runs.

Comment: Wow, super nice function! :)

Comment: Why are you using 1990s-style 8-bit colors?

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you're trying to generate a random colour each time for every user and store it in the Firebase? Correct me if I'm wrong.

I hope this solution would fix your issue of creating random colours each time. In short, wherever and whenever you need a random unique colour - call the method and check if the returned UIColor already exists in the database. If it doesn't exist then use it!

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

I hope the above solution from Oscar De Moya's from https://classictutorials.com/2014/08/generate-a-random-color-in-swift/ would help you.

Comment: OP wants to generate a distinct and constant color, so it must be generated base on uuid not with arc4random.

Comment: Thanks, this would be the solution I would use if I can't generate an UIColor from the userId. It would really be optimal though if I could use the userId somehow to create the UIColor.