# How to generate a random but unique color for each UUID in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to generate a random but unique UIColor for each UUID. Currently, I'm using this method but this method doesn't provide red/orange/yellow colours for ids. More specifically, I want to generate a colour scheme like WhatsApp group chat where each user has a unique title colour.

```
func getColorFromUUID(uuid:String) -> UIColor {
        var hexa = ""
        hexa += uuid.prefix(2)

        let indexMid = uuid.index(uuid.startIndex, offsetBy: uuid.count/2 + 1)
        let indexMidNext = uuid.index(uuid.startIndex, offsetBy: uuid.count/2 + 1)
        let mid = String.init(uuid[indexMid])
        let midNext = String.init(uuid[indexMidNext])
        hexa +=  mid
        hexa += midNext

        hexa += uuid.suffix(2)

        return self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: hexa)

    }

func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
        }

        if ((cString.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.gray
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }
```

Comment: If you want to have colors that match, but with a different hue, you should use [hue/saturation/brightness color space](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621931-init). Fixate saturation and brightness, and set hue according to `UUID` hash

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161221/swift-convert-string-to-hex-color-code

Comment: As uuid are random do you need to use it to generate the colour?  Can’t you use any random colour as long as you can ensure it’s unique and can store it for the uuid?

Comment: You should store any color you used. Then you can check if its a duplicate.

Comment: @flanker, he needs a function `f` from UUID to UIColor, and if there are two `x: UUID` and `y: UUID` where if `x == y` then `f(x) == f(y)`.

Comment: @user28434 yep, I understand the question asked, but is that really the requirement, or is it just for a unique colour for each uuid.  If it's not seeded on the uuid then it becomes easier to bias the HSB values towards brighter colours.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple way to think about it, colours are essentially represented by the numbers between 0 and 0xffffff. To get a number between 0 and 0xffffff from a string, you can get the hash code of the string, and `% 0x1000000`. Then you can extract the RGBs with bit masks:

```
func color(forUUID uuid: String) -> UIColor {
    let hash = uuid.hash
    let colorCode = abs(hash) % 0x1000000
    let red = colorCode >> 16
    let green = (colorCode >> 8) & 0xff
    let blue = colorCode & 0xff
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(red) / 256, green: CGFloat(green) / 256, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 256, alpha: 1)
}
```

[image]

In the comments, you mentioned that you only want 256 unique colours. In that case, `% 256` will do. You then pass the result to the HSB initialiser for `UIColor`:

```
func color(forUUID uuid: String) -> UIColor {
    let hash = uuid.hash
    let hue = abs(hash) % 256
    return UIColor(hue: CGFloat(hue) / 256, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Bad idea to use `.hash` — it would be a different value each time you run the app. Oh wait, it's `hashValue`

Comment: Also %256 does not guarantee unique values, does it?! Collisions are possible.

Comment: @MaticOblak The OP worded it badly. As the OP has said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59027863/how-to-generate-a-random-but-unique-color-for-each-uuid-in-swift/59028374?noredirect=1#comment104300163_59027980), he only needs (a mapping from UUIDs to) 256 different colours. The word "unique" is quite redundant here, as it means "the 256 colours are different". It doesn't mean "there should be a bijection between the UUIDs and the colours".

Comment: @Sweeper maybe my English just got a bit worse but I would say that "colour scheme like WhatsApp group chat where each user has a unique title colour" means EXACTLY that!

Comment: @MaticOblak I just checked one of my WhatsApp groups which has a lot of people, and found two people with exactly the same colour, confirmed with Digital Color Meter.

Comment: @Sweeper I apologize for adding a whole comment. Let me rephrase: "colour scheme like some-other-app-I-checked group chat where each user has a unique title colour" means EXACTLY that! The point being on "where each user has a unique title colour". Your finding though is a good argument to point out to OP and let him know that even WhatsApp doesn't have this all figured out.

Comment: @MaticOblak, you **can't have absolutely unique colors for every user**, so your objections in the comments doesn't make sense. WhatsApp and OP just do color indication to allow users do visual look up in the list faster by using multiple color indication.

Comment: @user28434 You are absolutely right. That is what I pointed out on a comment in the other answer. But it is possible to have 256 users within 1 group to have different colors. And to me it looks like this is implied. But if you do that then you can not have the same color throughout different groups. Not sure if WhatsApp persists colors or not though.

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is a way to color by UUID so that adjacent objects on the screen can be easily differentiated, you don't need a unique color for each UUID.  I had this exact same issue and found that different coloring algorithms tended to generate muted colors that tended to grey.

Instead of using an RGB Color value, using an HSV coloring scheme with saturation and value maxed out, will yield more varied vibrant results.

I suggest only using a single byte of the UUID to do the calculation of hue. Using more than one byte is that the more bytes that are used the lower the probability to get the extreme values of 0 or 1. The more bytes that are used, the more the value would tend toward .5.

Think of a pair of dice - the probability that a single dice would be a 1 is 1/6. And each value has the same chance. If you use 2 dice (like in craps), the probability of getting a 2 is 1/12, a 3 is 2/12, a 4 is 3/12, a 5 is 4/12, a 6 is 5/12, a 7 is 6/12, an 8 is 5/12, a 9 is 4/12, a 10 is 3/12, an 11 is 2/12, and a 12 is 1/12. This give us a bell curve distribution. Using a single dice gives us a more even distribution. Applying that logic to the UUID issue, using a single byte SHOULD give us a more even distribution with each value having a 1/256 chance.

At least in theory.  When I looked closer at the UUIDS, I noticed the absolute value of the first byte of every single UUID is always 64 or greater. However the second byte of the UUID varied a lot more and gave a more even distribution.

Using a long value (8 bytes) yields this image:

```
final long lsb = Math.abs(val.getLeastSignificantBits());
final double colorGen = (double) lsb / Long.MAX_VALUE;
// the intent is to get an evenly distributed value between 0 and 1
final int rgb[] = ColorUtils.HSVtoRGB(colorGen, 1.0, 1.0);
return new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

[image: using 8 bytes]

using a single byte yields this image:

```
  final long lsb = Math.abs(val.getLeastSignificantBits());
  final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES).putLong(lsb);
  final byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
  final double colorGen = Math.abs((short)bytes[1]) / 128.0;
  final int rgb[] = ColorUtils.HSVtoRGB(colorGen, 1.0, 1.0);

  return new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

[image: using a single byte]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. UUID Combinations are a lot more that the numbers of colors that you can create with RGB(255*255*255). The number of compinations in UUID is 2^128. Read [here for uuid](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) and section **How color spaces fit into RGBA values** [here](https://medium.com/@volbap/working-efficiently-with-colors-in-xcode-bc4c58b16f9a)

Comment: Well 256 colours would be enough. I only need 256 unique bright colour shades.

Comment: You will still have dublicates. You can make an approach based UUID but it will not be unique

Comment: Could you store the values serverside? Then you could match the group-participant's UUID to a specific colour when the group is generated and return all the user-colour matching back to the devices.

Comment: Check the section How color spaces fit into RGBA values https://medium.com/@volbap/working-efficiently-with-colors-in-xcode-bc4c58b16f9a

Comment: The UUIDs are already stored at server side. I map the UUID to a colour using the method above but it doesn't give me brighter colours like orange,red,yellow etc.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted as I think this actually touches the vital issue. @OmairAhmed the question here is if you need to seed your color with UUID. That would mean that if you are looking at chat groups then each user would preserve his own color throughout the groups. In that case even if you have a limit of 256 people in a single group you would have collisions in other groups which extends 256 people to as many as you have users. And that is exactly what this answer points out. Maybe you will need to think about a bit more how you want to distribute your colors.

Comment: UUID is not letters/number/chars. UUID is a *number*, 128bit number. That has common string representation. You don't need to do that weird "26 letters * 10 numbers * 32 chars" math.

Comment: Yes but based on UUID, uuidString is being created and uuid string has these limitation so if uuid is uniqe same thing is for uuidString and if uuidString has that math of combinations so uuid. please check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid/1779712-uuidstring

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ., `uuidString` is just a string representation of 128 bit number. One `uuidString` represents one 128 bit number, and one 128 bit UUID can be represented in a string exactly in one way. And it's easier to calculate `2^128` than do that string/digit/etc product.

Comment: yes you are correct I editted my answer, it's almost the same result with 32^(26 + 10) but your calculation is correct

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is exactly possible. At least not the way you describe it in both question and comments.

If I understand this correctly you expect to have "rooms" or groups of people where each person should get a color so it is nicely distinguished who writes what. You seem to expect up to 256 people but I am guessing you expect that within a single group.

If user UUID is used to determine a user color then the limit of 256 people helps nothing at all. When user is in group A he needs to have a different color than the rest of 255 people. When he is in group B he needs it different than rest 255 people in that group. So that means he would still need to dodge ALL users in your database. As already mentioned there are not enough colors for that.

A solution is possible to do this per-room though. You could do it either on server or on client. On client something like the following should work:

```
class User {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
}

class Room {

    private var users: [User] = []
    private var colors: [String: UIColor] = [String: UIColor]()

    var availableColors: [UIColor] = {
        let count: Int = 256
        var colors: [UIColor] = []
        for index in 0..<count {
            let color = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(index)/CGFloat(count), saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            colors.append(color)
        }
        return colors
    }()

    func addUser(_ user: User) {
        users.append(user)
        colors[user.id] = availableColors.remove(at: Int(arc4random())%availableColors.count)
    }

    func removeUser(_ user: User) {
        if let color = colors[user.id] {
            availableColors.append(color)
        }
        users = users.filter { $0.id != user.id }
    }

    func colorForUser(_ user: User) -> UIColor {
        return colors[user.id] ?? UIColor.black
    }

}
```

This now generates 256 colors and the system will select a random one for each user. This system may still not be the best as for one in 256 colors you can already have similar colors. And if there are 2 people in group and both have similar color that would be pretty bad if you ask me (and the chances for it are relatively high in this case).

I would rather try to actually just randomize the first value and then dodge it. Consider something like this:

```
func generateRandomColorList(limit: Int = 256) -> [UIColor] {
    var hues: [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
    hues.append(CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)) // Initial value is random
    while hues.count < limit {
        let offset = 0.5/CGFloat(hues.count)
        hues.forEach { hue in
            let newHue = hue + offset
            hues.append(newHue > 1.0 ? newHue - 1.0 : newHue) // If it gets past 1.0 just rotate it back
        }
    }
    return hues.map { UIColor(hue: $0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) }
}
```

The idea is that the returned array starts randomly but it is then ordered so that it dodges current value as much as it can. You would then use it like `colors[user.id] = availableColors.removeFirst()`. There would still be some possible improvements like scrambling order of each orbital:

```
        let offset = 0.5/CGFloat(hues.count)
        var circle: [CGFloat] = []
        hues.forEach { hue in
            let newHue = hue + offset
            circle.append(newHue > 1.0 ? newHue - 1.0 : newHue) // If it gets past 1.0 just rotate it back
        }
        hues.append(contentsOf: circle.randomlyOrdered())
```

If you manage to implement something like that it seems that you may actually develop a better algorithm than our beloved WhatsApp.